# Parts for Cathode Ray Oscilloscope

Tags: operational-amplifier, cathode-ray-oscilloscope

I am building a CRO. I made a circuit for it but I am not able to figure out which parts to use. Can anyone suggest low noise high frequency (at least 1 MHz unity gain) op amp which can give at least 15 mA output ? Also I am finding IC capable of producing 100 kHz PWM signal at 1% or lower duty cycle.

Comment: The difficulty is probably not in finding an op-amp with the desired gain bandwidth or low noise rating, but finding all of that at the high voltages required to drive a cathode ray tube.  Are you seriously building an oscilloscope with a CRT, or are you just building a digitizer that will display the results on an LCD or computer display?  Also, what's with the 100 kHz PWM circuit?  What do you plan to do  with it?

Comment: I am attempting to modify my old CRT TV to CRO. It uses magnetic field for deflecting electrons. I am using op amp to amplify sawtooth wave for driving bjts which will then drive coils for horizontal deflection. similar for vertical deflection. yes i want op amps with around +-15 max volt input. 100khz pwm is for producing sawtooth wave.

Comment: You will not be able to get more than audio bandwidth with magnetic deflection.

Comment: i know that. but i am not a professional so don't want to blow hole in my pocket for equipments.

Comment: You can get a scope for a couple hundred$

Comment: Your horizontal flyback transformer only goes at a fixed frequency unless you DIY XY mode

Comment: Please move the information about your project goals into the main body of the question, that way readers won't have to search for it in the comments.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 audio bandwidth for much less (in fact, for AC, your soundcard or a 3€ USB sound card does just fine, and the bit depth is astonishing)

Comment: Yes audio DSO’s are free open software using sound card with > 4 or 5 decades  @MarcusMüller